# How do I send multiple Json data using HttpPost in android

Tags: android, json

```
[
   {
    "val1" : -1,
    "val2" : -1,
    "id" : 0,
    "diff" : -1,
    },
{
   ….
 }
]
```

I have a list of data that I need to send to the server. I am sending al the data via HttpPost 
I got the data in Json and created a string as follows but how do I send all the data and not just that one string together. On the server side it takes 50 such data list.

```
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
      ArrayList<String> mydata = new ArrayList<String> data();

      String json = "";
      jsonObject.accumulate("val1", val);
      jsonObject.accumulate("val2", val2);
      jsonObject.accumulate("id", id);
      jsonObject.accumulate("diff", diff);
      json = jsonObject.toString();
       mydata.add(json);
```

EDIT: On using JSONArray:  {"Status":{"Code":699,"Description":"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Single' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.\u000d\u000aTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\u000d\u000aPath '[0].Speed', line 1, position 11."}}

Comment: in json terms, you'd be building an array of your individual lists. `[{"val1":1},{"val1":2},{"val2":3}, etc...}]`

Comment: So If I create a String array what would the httpPost.setEntity(?) be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [JsonArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) instance not appending the JsonObject result String to an ArrayList.

and the second fault is that you are using [accumulate](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#accumulate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) rather than [put](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) map the key to the value because the accumulate method appends the value to a JsonArray mapped to the key you provided.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
// for every item in the 50 item you need to send
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("val1", val);
jsonObject.put("val2", val2);
jsonObject.put("id", id);
jsonObject.put("diff", diff);
jsonArray.put(obj);
// then you need to send the data to the server
String data = jsonArray.toString();
```

Comment: I had not changed it to PUT and used accumulate which gave me that error. Thanks